# how i can make login with face book

Tags: php

how i can make login with face book
i want an php code or class let me making that

Comment: go to developers zone of facebook , http://developers.facebook.com/ you will find necessary info there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best resource is probably http://developers.facebook.com/